# Connecting wires to form loops. Probability of one loop

Tags: probability

The question:

> 10 wires each of length 1 mile lay parallel to each other. Electrician
> A can only see one side of the wires, while Electrician B can only see
> the other side of the wires. They randomly connect pairs of distinct
> wire ends until all ends are accounted for. What is the probability
> that the connections form a closed circuit with total length 10 miles?

My approach: If Electrician A connects wire $i$ and $j$ and Electrician B connects wires $i$ and $j$, then this is violated. So for every connection $C = (i, j)$ that A makes, B cannot make connection $C$. We can arbitrarily assign Electrician A's wires and then check the probability that Electrician B will have all different connections by symmetry.

Let $D$ be the event that B has all different connections. $P(D) = 1 - P(D^c)$.

Let A have connections $A_1, ..., A_5$, and B have connections $B_1, ..., B_5$.

$P(D) = P(A_i \neq B_j) \forall i, j$
$$P(D^c) = P(\bigcup_{0 \leq i, j \leq 5} A_i = B_j)$$

Using Principle of inclusion/exclusion and chain rule of probabilities, we can generate the following expression:

$${5\choose1}\frac{1}{9}  - {5\choose2} \frac{1}{9 \cdot 7} + {5\choose3}\frac{1}{9\cdot7\cdot5} - {5\choose4}\frac{1}{9\cdot7\cdot5\cdot3} + {5\choose5}\frac{1}{9\cdot7\cdot5\cdot3\cdot1}$$

Generally, this came from this idea: Without loss of generality, let's assume $A_1 = (1, 2)$. Then $P(B_j = A_1)$ is the probability any of B's connections are $(1, 2)$. One of the connections certainly contains $1$, and given this, the probability it is connected to $2$ is just $\frac{1}{9}$, as every number $2, ..., 10$ is equally likely. The multiplication by 5 is to do this process for each $A_i$. Then the next term is the probability two of A's connections are contained in B. Similarly, for $A_1$, we can say B has a probability $\frac{1}{9}$ to have wire $1$ connected to $2$. Without loss of generality, let's assume $A_2 = (3, 4)$. Conditioning on $A_1$ being contained in B's connections, we can check to see if wire $3$ is connected to wire $4$. There are $7$ remaining wires, so there is probability $\frac{1}{7}$. This process continues for the rest.

This ultimately yields $P(D^c) = \frac{5}{9} - \frac{10}{63} + \frac{10}{315} - \frac{5}{945} + \frac{1}{945} = \frac{401}{945}$. This would mean $P(D) = \frac{544}{945}$.

The solution says the following:

There are $10$ ends on the left side of the wires and $10$ ends on the right side of the wires. Without loss of generality, we connect the right end of the first wire to the right end of the second wire. In order to retain the possibility of forming a $10$ mile loop, there are $8$ possible left wire ends with which the left end of the second wire can join with, out of a possible $9$. Without loss of generality, we connect the left end of the second wire to the left end of the third wire. The right end of the third wire can then be joined with any other remaining wire's right end. Back to the left end. There are $7$ remaining ends on the left side. Of these, $6$ are viable connections. Repeating this process, we get a final answer of:
$$\frac{8}{9}\cdot\frac{6}{7}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\cdot\frac{2}{3} = \frac{128}{315}$$.

I don't quite understand this solution. Let me give an example. Suppose A = $\{(1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 7), (6, 8), (9, 10)\}$. If we go using their solution. For B, the solution proposes that $8$ of the $9$ are valid, so let's choose (1, 2). Then let's repeat this process to get the first 4 connections for B: $\{(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)\}$. Then, the remaining wire would not be valid in this simulation, but their solution implies it will. However, this would mean their solution is too high, but my solution is even higher, so I am definitely wrong. Could someone either correct me and explain why the solution is correct, or could they invalidate both of these and explain. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example does not satisfy the solution proposed, but it also does not satisfy the construction procedure, so it is really not surprising. Following your example, if we imagine that $B$ starts connecting $(1,2)$, then $A$ has 8 out of 9 options to connect $2$, in your example $(2,4)$. After that, $B$ connects $(3,4)$, and now $A$ has to connect $3$ to any of $1,5,6,7,8,9,10$. However, in your example, $1$ has already been used before, which would close a loop. Electrician $A$ should actually exclude wire $1$, hence the factor $6/7$. So your counterexample is flawed.

As for your solution, it is true that $A$ and $B$ cannot make a common connection, as you correctly noticed, but this only avoids 2km loops. It does not avoid $4$, $6$ or $8$ km long loops. That is why your solution is larger than the correct one: you are not properly filtering what you are asked for. You could correct your approach by finding the probabilities for all of these longer loops, but it looks way more convoluted than the solution of the book. I would recommend spending some more time thinking about why this solution makes sense, rather than extending your initial approach.